# Как организовать ввод данных в массив с клавиатуры в php?

Tags: php

Я не знаю как организовать ввод данных с клавиатуры в php, посмотрел на форумах, там пишут, что php не работает с драйверами компьютера поэтому нельзя
Но если как-то можно, то подскажите, пожалуйста

```
<?php
$array1 = array("Москва","Воронеж", "Казань", "Белгород","Тверь","Амстердам","Минск");
$array2 = array("Белгород", "Орел", "Москва","Киев", "Казань","Амстердам","Нижний Новгород");

echo "Массив 1: ";
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
if (in_array($item, $array2)) {
echo '<span style="color:green;">'. $item.' </span>';
}
else {
echo '<span style="color:red;">'. $item.' </span>';
}
}
echo "<br>";
echo "Массив 2: ";
foreach ($array2 as $item) {
if (in_array($item, $array1)) {
echo '<span style="color:green;">'. $item.' </span>';
}
else {
echo '<span style="color:red;">'. $item.' </span>';
}
}
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: это дичь какая то)) можно через прокладку вроде ajax посредством запросов туда/сюда гонять данные..

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать глобальный масив $_POST.

Вот пример формы:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="city[]" value="London" />
<input type="text" name="city[]" value="Kiev">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

В консоли можно работать с потоком ввода

Пример:

```
<?php


$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

echo 'Type your value > '; 
echo 'Your value: ' . fgets($stdin);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: у меня таким способом записывается только один город и дальше не работает

Comment: @buzzinga Я обновил код, можете добавлять поля используя js до бесконечность, если с js нужна помощь, то пишите.